# How to get value from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable in mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I know the title is somewhat complicate but let I clear the title by explaining the problem.

[image]
As per image I want to filter product name in search textbox. For ex: In search textbox if I enter the oil that in datatable whole data want to show which product name is oil.

For filter I used linq query, here is my code,

```
var dataList = (from x in query
    select new
    {
        PartName = _Db.Part.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.PartId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.Name),
        ManufacturerName = _Db.Manufacture.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.ManufacturerId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.name),
        CategoryName = _Db.Category.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.Name),
        Pcs = x.Sum(o =>o.Pcs) - 
        (from m in _Db.MaterialRecord
           join s in _Db.ServiceJob on m.ServiceJobId equals s.Id
           where m.pid == x.Select(p => p.PartId).FirstOrDefault()
           select m).Sum(z => z.Qty),
        Weight = _Db.Purchase.Where(p => p.Weight == x.Select(s => s.Weight).FirstOrDefault()).Select(a => a.Weight).FirstOrDefault(),      
        WeightType = x.Select(p => p.WeightTypeId).FirstOrDefault() > 0 ?((WeightType)x.Select(p => p.WeightTypeId).FirstOrDefault()).ToString() :"",
    }).ToList();

//Search    
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
    dataList = dataList.Where(m => m.CategoryName.Contains(searchValue.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();

//Returning Json Data
return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data });
```

As per code I am getting whole data in datalist variable. Now, when I search any product in searchbox at that time the condition of search will true and after that the datalist value will be null[as shown by debug the code].

So, hence from that datatable shows null data.

For understanding that why this happening I add the **tostring()** in datalist query of category line i.e.

```
CategoryName = _Db.Category.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.Name).toString(),
```

After adding **toString()** in this line it shows this line **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable**. But I want the result value of this line. For more clear lets see the another image

[image]

That **oil** result value I want in search condition line i.e.

```
dataList = dataList.Where(m => m.CategoryName.Contains(searchValue.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();
```

but right now in it is showing this line **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable** in the place of result value.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve with this line: `CategoryName = _Db.Category.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.Name)`?

Comment: @SeM this line shows the name of the category by the category table where in category table categoryid = purchase table categoryid.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should know is [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) by its default implementation returns fully-qualified name of the object when applied to collection objects, in this case returns `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<string>` which is a reference type that doesn't override that method.

Let's evaluate this expression first:

```
CategoryName = _Db.Category.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault())
                           .Select(p => p.Name),
```

Assumed that `Category` has `DbSet<Category>` type, the `Select()` extension method used in code above returns `EntityQueryable<string>` which contains result set collection from executed SQL statement provided by LINQ-to-Entities query. If you want to pull single string value from that collection, you must use one of the `First()`, `Single()`, `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` extension methods.

Hence, you should add extension method as mentioned above to return a string value instead of a collection:

```
var dataList = (from x in query
    select new {
        // other properties

        CategoryName = _Db.Category.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault())
                               .Select(p => p.Name).SingleOrDefault(),

        // other properties
    }).ToList();
```

Then you can use `Contains` against a substring (`searchValue`) because `CategoryName` has string type:

```
dataList = dataList.Where(m => m.CategoryName.Contains(searchValue.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();
```

Reference:

[Entity Framework/Core and LINQ to Entities Query Methods (Operators)](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-core-and-linq-to-entities-4-query-methods)