# Count cannot be used like a method in an ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

The title shows me the an error i.e. Count cannot be used like a method. This error shows in runtime in controller side.

Here is my code,

```
var dataList = (dynamic)null;

// Search    
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
{
    dataList = (from x in query
                select new
                       {
                            PartName = _Db.Part.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.PartId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.Name),
                            ManufacturerName = _Db.Manufacture.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.ManufacturerId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.name),
                            CategoryName = _Db.Category.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.Name == searchValue.ToString()),
                            Pcs = x.Sum(o => o.Pcs) - (from m in _Db.MaterialRecord
                                                       join s in _Db.ServiceJob on m.ServiceJobId equals s.Id
                                                       where m.pid == x.Select(p => p.PartId).FirstOrDefault()
                                                       select m).Sum(z => z.Qty),
                            Weight = _Db.Purchase.Where(p => p.Weight == x.Select(s => s.Weight).FirstOrDefault()).Select(a => a.Weight).FirstOrDefault(),
                            WeightType = x.Select(p => p.WeightTypeId).FirstOrDefault() > 0 ? ((WeightType)x.Select(p => p.WeightTypeId).FirstOrDefault()).ToString() : "",
                        }).ToList();
}
else
{
    dataList = (from x in query
        select new
        {
            PartName = _Db.Part.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.PartId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.Name),
            ManufacturerName = _Db.Manufacture.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.ManufacturerId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.name),
            CategoryName = _Db.Category.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.Name),
            Pcs = x.Sum(o => o.Pcs) -
            (from m in _Db.MaterialRecord
                join s in _Db.ServiceJob on m.ServiceJobId equals s.Id
                where m.pid == x.Select(p => p.PartId).FirstOrDefault()
                select m).Sum(z => z.Qty),
            Weight = _Db.Purchase.Where(p => p.Weight == x.Select(s => s.Weight).FirstOrDefault()).Select(a => a.Weight).FirstOrDefault(),

            WeightType = x.Select(p => p.WeightTypeId).FirstOrDefault() > 0 ? ((WeightType)x.Select(p => p.WeightTypeId).FirstOrDefault()).ToString() : "",
        }).ToList();
    }

    // total number of rows count     
    recordsTotal = dataList.Count();

    // Paging     
    var data = dataList.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

    // Returning Json Data
    return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data });
}
```

Now when I run the program at that time

```
recordsTotal = dataList.Count();
```

in this line shows this error:

> Non-invocable member 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType15,System.Linq.IQueryable,System.Linq.IQueryable,int,int,string>>.Count' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Have you tried just `recordsTotal = dataList.Count;` ?

Comment: The error is kinda self explanatory. Like Fildor mentioned, just remove the "()" after the count.

Comment: `var dataList = (dynamic)null;` I don't think this is right in your situation. Instead of handling value of `searchValue` in one line, inside `CategoryName`, you've duplicated whole code and went to casting your list to `dynamic`.

Comment: @SeM yah you right. Can you suggest me how I maintain code just for the search by my code. Please.

Comment: @SeM I have tried to do the different type of code but it shows the different error and that question I have shown here i.e. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252957/how-to-get-value-from-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-query-internal-entityqueryab**
but it didnt work thats why I am doing this type of code

Comment: @karan I don't think your code will work correctly if you resolve `Count` problem. There is a issue with `.Select(p => p.Name == searchValue.ToString()),`, which will return a collection of `bool`.

Comment: @SeM yes you are right for that I have change by
**CategoryName = _Db.Category.Where(z => z.Id == x.Select(p => p.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.Name.Contains(searchValue.ToString())),**
but showing the true, false value in the place of string value

Comment: @karan It will also return collection of `bool`s. If you need to filter, use `Where` then `Select`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186925/discussion-between-karan-and-sem).

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `Count()` method on `dynamic` type which is `List`. `Count()` method is extension to `IEnumerable<>`. You can use `Enumerable.Count()` method instead:

```
recordsTotal = Enumerable.Count(dataList);
```

or remove parenthesis:

```
// There is Count property in List<T>
recordsTotal = dataList.Count;
```

More details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object).