# Entity Framework Core returning Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String] instead of value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

newbie here to programming and EF Core. I have 3 tables: Product, ProductGroup, and a TransactionalData table. The transactional data table has a Product in the raw data but I need to lookup the ProductGroupName based on that Product. There is a FK relationship between Product and ProductGroup and that works fine for other actions. I have a SQL query that returns the correct name if I run directly in SQL Server but when using EF Core I'm getting Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String] instead of the ProductGroupName.

Here is my SQL query that returns the correct value:

```
select top 1 ProductGroupName from ProductGroup
inner join Product
on ProductGroup.Id = Product.ProductGroupId
where ProductName = @ProductName
```

Here is the query I'm using in C# for EF Core where "product" is the value from the TransactionalData table that I'm passing in:

```
var query = from p in _dbContext.Set<Product>()
            join g in _dbContext.Set<ProductGroup>()
                on p.ProductGroupId equals g.Id
            select g.ProductGroupName.Where(x => x.Equals(product)).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

My method is setup to return a string. I'm missing something here in the translation to the actual string I want for the name. Also that transactional data has thousands of records to iterate and assign that ProductGroupName to. Should I instead get a list of all the unique values of Product in the transactional data then lookup the ProductGroupName for those and assign that way?

I have tried a couple of different options in writing a stored procedure and executing that in EF core as well as a direct query in EF core and but returning some version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String] vs. the actual string value.

I saw a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252957/how-to-get-value-from-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-query-internal-entityqueryab) on Stack Overflow but it's not sinking into my brain.

Comment: I think you're getting EF wrong. You're supposed to navigate round the graph of objects on the context via their links, not use LINQ queries to join them together like some messed-up hybrid of C# and SQL. As it is, you're calling ToString on an instance of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable``1[System.String]` that FirstOrDefault is plucking out of a collection emitted by the query. Your EF should really be more like `_dbContext.Products.Where(p => p.ProductName == product).Select(p => p.ProductGroup.Name)`, using the relationship between Product and Group EF knows

Comment: `select g.ProductGroupName.Where(x => x.Equals(product)).FirstOrDefault().ToString()` is quite unusual (and wrong) expression. You probably want something like `where p.ProductName == product select g.ProductGroupName` instead,

Comment: @HasBeanCounter thank you! That helped me get the right value I needed and also where I need to focus on increasing my knowledge of EF querying.

Comment: @LizFleming I expanded the point in the comment above into an nswer below. If it helped your understanding you can upvote it. If contained the answer you were looking for you can click the check to mark your query as solved

Answer (score 0):

You're not using EF how it was intended to be used.

You're supposed to have a database, with a Products and a ProductGroups table, and they're related (apparently) in a sense of 1 product has 1 group, but 1 group has many products. Have a relationship that makes this clear in the DB and provides referential integrity

When you've generated a context for this correctly (tell EF to do it, to save you a bunch of work - if you've never done it, install the EF Core Power Tools extension and use it to Reverse Engineer your database) you'll have two classes with some notable properties:

```
class Product{
 //blah blah other props here
 
 ProductGroup ProductGroup{get;set;}
}
class ProductGroup{
 //blah blah other props here
 
 IList<Product> Products{get;set;}
}
```

Those two props are really important; they link Products and Groups together in C# and allow you to navigate from eg 1 product to its 1 group, or to start from 1 group and see all its list of related products

More importantly, when EF sees you using them in queries, it will make joins for you so you don't have to

If you want a product group that has a product with the name "X" you can either start from groups or start from products. Generally it's easier to navigate along a relationship in the "from the current object into its one related object" direction than in the "from the current object into one of its many relative" direction

Because a product has 1 group, we want the group name and we know the product name, let's look up the product, then navigate into its one group, and pull the name:

```
_dbContext.Products
  .Where(p => p.ProductName == "X")
  .Select(p => p.ProductGroup.ProductGroupName)
```

There might be many products that have that name, so this will still return a collection (even if the collection has only one entry because the name is unique). It's a job for you to decide how to resolve two products in different groups having X as a name, but to get the ProductGroupName you've selected you need something to give you that, like `.First()` after the `Select(..)`

The joining happens automatically because you used a navigation in the `Select`, so EF can see you navigating from product to group and it knows it has to do  a join to satisfy that (or some other magic like multiple queries)

You don't have to use where/select - you can alternatively tell EF which related objects to bring, as whole objects. It might be a more compact form of code because it combines the Where and the resolution of the "multiple products called X" into a single call to First, but it will download more data:

```
_dbContext.Products
  .Include(p => o.ProductGroup)
  .First(p => p.ProductName == "X")
  .ProductGroup.ProductGroupName
```

Here EF will download an entire product and related group row, populate two related objects, give you the product object (that has a group associated), and you'll throw most of it away when you just pull the name.

It's still important to note that joining automagically still happens here because you asked for a product that includes the related group, so EF will fetch the related details however it wants to

This approach skips the Select; it could have used it to download less data. There are plenty of ways to skin the cat, and you use different ones depending on differnet situations - do you want updateable graphs of whole related objects? Do you want a few props of some objects? What other data will you need later? These are the questions to answer when deciding an approach

You're still only working with the abstraction of EF - you're not force joining for it etc, nor writing stuff that looks like SQL. EF is trying to make the DB look like just a bunch of related objects and you travel round the connections between them

---

You can go the other way, and start from groups. This way you want "a group where any of its related products has a name of X":

```
_dbContext.ProductGroups
  .Where(pg => pg.Products.Any(p => p.ProductName == "X"))
  .Select(pg => pg.ProductGroupName)
```

This still produces potentially multiple results, so you still have to resolve that (e.g. a First) if you only want one, but EF will probably translate this to an EXISTS query rather than a join because you don't really want to bring the related data. Ultimately you don't care how EF does what it does, until you're looking at a performance issue with the SQL it has formed and want to change the SQL to change the performance

Main message: move away from "just writing SQL in some altered C# flavored dialect in C#" and towards this notion of "EF knows how to make SQL joins when it sees you navigating around the object graph in C#". Treat your context like C# objects that link to each other and leave EF alone to do its stuff.

Side message: decide what data you want and pick a good place to start from, crawling round your obejct graph in various places and ways, and let EF do what it does. If you hit the wall that it can;t translate what you wrote, you then start getting cuter with how you ask, or doing more raw operations to help it out but that's a long way from "the group with a product whose name is X" level

---

If these relationships don't exist in the DB side and hence EF is ignorant of them and you don't get these nav props when you reverse/scaffold your DB, you should create them so that EF can leverage them. If youre going to fill C# with `from x join y where z select a` you're mostly missing the point of EF, and Dapper might be better for you